# XSL for-each call template on nodes with specific value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Having a XML-structure like this:

```
<ContextDoc>
  <PurchaseOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <OrderForms>
      <OrderForm>
        <Shipments>
          <Shipment>
            ...
            <ShippingMethodId>17995798-a2cc-43ad-81e8-bb932f6827e4</ShippingMethodId>
            ...
          </Shipment>
          <Shipment>
            ...
            <ShippingMethodId>11223344-a2cc-11bc-25a7-aa345f6827e6</ShippingMethodId>
            ...
          </Shipment>
        </Shipments>
        <LineItems>
          <LineItem>
            ...
            <ShippingMethodId>17995798-a2cc-43ad-81e8-bb932f6827e4</ShippingMethodId>
            ...
          </LineItem>
          <LineItem>
            ...
            <ShippingMethodId>17995798-a2cc-43ad-81e8-bb932f6827e4</ShippingMethodId>
            ...
          </LineItem>
          <LineItem>
            ...
            <ShippingMethodId>11223344-a2cc-11bc-25a7-aa345f6827e6</ShippingMethodId>
            ...
          </LineItem>
        </LineItems>
      </OrderForm>
    </OrderForms>
  </PurchaseOrder>
</ContextDoc>
```

From the template matching each Shipment node I want to loop the LineItems with the current ShippingMethodId. Like so:

```
<xsl:template match="Shipment">
    <xsl:for-each select="//LineItems/LineItem[ShippingMethodId=./ShippingMethodId]">
      <xsl:call-template name="LineItem">
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:Template>
```

But that gives me all LineItems under each Shipment. What is the correct way to call the template for the specific LineItem nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current) to point to the context outside the loop. The `.` inside the loop points to the context of the current element of the lopp. Like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//LineItems/LineItem[ShippingMethodId=current()/ShippingMethodId]">
```

also, it feels like you can do all you need with "matching" and without calling out templates like functions. Give us a little more idea about what you're trying to accomplish and we will likely recommend a more ideomatic way to get there. For example, if you need to group by those `ShippingMethodId`s you can use the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).